# How to get an array of response in php

Tags: php

I am having this code below

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM users");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(
    [
    'user' => array_reverse($result),
    ]);
```

Which gives me this response below which is an array of object.

```
 "user": [{
        "name": "Jules"
    }, {
        "name": "Anna"
    }]
```

But I want a response like this, which is just an array.

```
 "user": [
      "Jules",
       "Anna"
   ]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Loop thru the map and save the names to an array? You could also just order the entries in the SQL query

Comment: then you should transform the $result array in php so that it looks like what you expect in the outout json

Comment: So where are you stuck with the transformation?

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/df4a00 to show the map that was suggested

Comment: @BilalSloni I shared the php code (in a live snippet) to transform the $result array in the array you expect to see in json. You are just supposed to pass that array to json_encode. Did you see it?

Comment: @Diego De Vita Yes I have seen it, Thank you so much for the help, I appreciate :)